# References about Zariski Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I ask about  Zariski topology. I want references (books,notes online,...) that have more examples and explanation. I just took last week in m commutative algebra.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Zariski topology on $\Bbb P^n$, Zariski topology on $\operatorname{Spec}R$ or both?

Comment: Just on $Spec R$

Comment: Take any introductory text on (modern) algebraic geometry or even the most commutative algebra texts.

Answer (score 3):

An Introduction to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah-McDonald is a good reference for this.

Comment: Agree, more precisely all exercises of chapter 1.